# How to solve a json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: json, python-3.x

I was trying to get the data from a .json file with the python JSON library and I keep getting a json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) error. I tried replacing the data in the json file with {"test": "test"} and I still get the error and I printed the file with f.read()
here's my code

```
with open("items.json", 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
    items = json.load(f)
```

and the json file

```
{
    "test": "test"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can print your json:

```
import json

with open('items.json') as f:
  data = json.load(f)

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem by using this code instead:

```
f = open('items.json', 'r')
items = json.load(f)
f.close()
```